problem with adjusting the size of codemirror within its parent
What I’m trying to do is create a code editor with a user interface similar to vscode. I used split.js to scale between the editor (codemirror editor inside tabs) and sidebars.
The problem is that when a number of lines or characters are entered, instead of the scroller appearing, the editor expands and its container expands with it beyond the size limits.
I am almost a beginner, so perhaps the problem is in the layout and I did not notice it.


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>My IDE</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/codemirror.min.css">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

</head>

<body>



  <div class="main-container">

    <!-- Title bar -->

    <div class="title-bar">

        <!-- Menus -->

        <div class="menus">

            <div class="menu-item">File</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Edit</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Selection</div>

            <div class="menu-item">View</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Go</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Run</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Terminal</div>

            <div class="menu-item">Help</div>

        </div>

        <!-- Title -->

        <div class="title">Title</div>

        <!-- Window control buttons -->

        <div class="window-controls">

            <button class="minimize">-</button>

            <button class="restore">+</button>

            <button class="close">X</button>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Secondary container -->

    <div class="secondary-container">

        <!-- Activity bar items -->

        <div class="activity-bar">

            <div class="activity-bar-items">

                <div class="activity-bar-item active" id="explorer">Explorer</div>

                <div class="activity-bar-item" id="search">Search</div>

                <div class="activity-bar-item" id="source-control">Source Control</div>

                <div class="activity-bar-item" id="debug">Debug</div>

                <div class="activity-bar-item" id="extensions">Extensions</div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Split container -->

        <div class="split-container">

            <!-- Sidebar -->

            <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

            <!-- Editor -->

            <div class="editor"></div>

            <!-- Secondary sidebar -->

            <div class="secondary-sidebar">Secondary Sidebar</div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Status bar -->

    <div class="status-bar">Status Bar</div>

</div>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/codemirror.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.3/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>



  <script src="https://unpkg.com/split.js/dist/split.min.js"></script>

 

  <!-- <script src="scripts/javascript/activity_bar/activity_bar.js"></script> -->

  <script src="scripts/javascript/editor/editor.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts/javascript/split_container/split_container.js"></script>

  <!-- <script src="scripts/javascript/status_bar/status_bar.js"></script> -->

  <!-- <script src="scripts/javascript/title_bar/title_bar.js"></script> -->



</body>

</html>

editor.js:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const editorContainer = document.querySelector(".editor");

    const tabBar = document.createElement("div");

    tabBar.className = "tab-bar";



    const addTabButton = document.createElement("button");

    addTabButton.className = "add-tab-button";

    addTabButton.innerHTML = "+";



    tabBar.appendChild(addTabButton);

    editorContainer.appendChild(tabBar);



    const editors = {};

    let activeTabId = null;

    let tabCounter = 0;



    function createEditor() {

        const editorElement = document.createElement("div");

        editorElement.className = "code-editor";



        const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

    textarea.className = "text-area";

        editorElement.appendChild(textarea);



        editorContainer.appendChild(editorElement);



        const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {

            lineNumbers: true,

            mode: "javascript",

            theme: "default",

            lineWrapping: false, // Disable line wrapping

            matchBrackets: true,

            autoCloseBrackets: true,

        });

        return { editorElement, editor };

    }





    function createTab() {

        const tabId = `tab-${tabCounter++}`;

        const tabButton = document.createElement("button");

        tabButton.className = "tab-button";

        tabButton.dataset.tabId = tabId;

        tabButton.innerHTML = `Tab ${tabCounter} <span class="close-tab">x</span>`;



        tabBar.insertBefore(tabButton, addTabButton);



        const { editorElement, editor } = createEditor();



        editors[tabId] = { tabButton, editorElement, editor };



        tabButton.addEventListener("click", () => switchTab(tabId));

        tabButton.querySelector(".close-tab").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

            e.stopPropagation();

            closeTab(tabId);

        });



        switchTab(tabId);

    }



    function switchTab(tabId) {

        if (activeTabId) {

            const { tabButton, editorElement } = editors[activeTabId];

            tabButton.classList.remove("active");

            editorElement.style.display = "none";

        }



        const { tabButton, editorElement, editor } = editors[tabId];

        tabButton.classList.add("active");

        editorElement.style.display = "block";

        editor.refresh();



        activeTabId = tabId;

    }



    function closeTab(tabId) {

        const { tabButton, editorElement } = editors[tabId];

        tabButton.remove();

        editorElement.remove();



        delete editors[tabId];



        if (activeTabId === tabId) {

            const remainingTabIds = Object.keys(editors);

            if (remainingTabIds.length > 0) {

                switchTab(remainingTabIds[0]);

            } else {

                activeTabId = null;

            }

        }

    }



    addTabButton.addEventListener("click", createTab);

    createTab();  // Open an initial tab

});

split_container.js:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    // Initialize Split.js for the split container

    Split(['.sidebar', '.editor', '.secondary-sidebar'], {

        sizes: [20, 60, 20], // Initial sizes of each panel

        minSize: 100, // Minimum size of each panel

        gutterSize: 5, // Size of the draggable gutter

        cursor: 'col-resize', // Cursor style when dragging

        direction: 'horizontal' // Direction of the split

    });



    

});

css:


/* default.css */



/* Set html and body to take full viewport height */

html, body {

  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}



/* Main container styles */

.main-container {

    background-color: #220055ff;

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100vh;

    

    max-height: 100%;

    max-width: 100%;

}



/* Title bar styles */

.title-bar {

    display: flex;

    justify-content: space-between;

    align-items: center;

    padding: 0 10px;

    background-color: #333;

    color: white;

}



.title {

    font-size: 18px;

}



.window-controls {

    display: flex;

}



.window-controls button {

    margin-left: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

}



/* Menus styles */

.menus {

    display: flex;

}



.menu-item {

    padding: 5px 10px;

    cursor: pointer;

}



/* Secondary container styles */

.secondary-container {

    display: flex;

    flex: 1;

}



/* Activity bar styles */

.activity-bar {

    background-color: #444;

    color: white;

    width: 70px;

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}



.activity-bar-items {

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}



.activity-bar-item {

    padding: 10px;

    cursor: pointer;

    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;

}



.activity-bar-item.active {

    background-color: #007acc;

    color: white;

}



/* Split container styles */

.split-container {

    background-color: #00ffffff;

    display: flex;

    flex: 1;



    

}



/* Sidebar styles */

.sidebar {

    width: 200px;

    background-color: #eee;

    padding: 10px;

}



/* Editor styles */

.editor {

    background-color: #ff00ffff;

    display: flex;

    flex:1;

    flex-direction: column;

    overflow: hidden;

    /*height: 100%;*/

    /*max-height: 600px;*/ /* Adjust the maximum height as needed */

    

}





.code-editor {

    max-width: 100%;

    max-height: 100%;

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

}



.CodeMirror {

    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

    max-width: 100%;

    max-height: 100%;

}







.tab-bar {

    display: flex;

    background-color: #ddd;

    padding: 0.5rem;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}



.tab-button {

    background-color: #eee;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    margin-right: 0.5rem;

    padding: 0.5rem;

    cursor: pointer;

    position: relative;

}



.tab-button.active {

    background-color: #fff;

    border-bottom: none;

    padding-bottom: 1rem;

}



.tab-button .close-tab {

    position: absolute;

    right: 5px;

    top: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

}



.add-tab-button {

    background-color: #ccc;

    border: 1px solid #bbb;

    padding: 0.5rem;

    cursor: pointer;

}









/* Secondary sidebar styles */

.secondary-sidebar {

    width: 150px;

    background-color: #ddd;

    padding: 10px;

}



/* Status bar styles */

.status-bar {

    padding: 5px 10px;

    background-color: #333;

    color: white;

}

I am almost a beginner, so perhaps the problem is in the layout and I did not notice it.

Use css overflow:scroll propertyDoes only work if you define a height -> scroll-y or width scroll-x or both.
Open html in browser , right click on your editor field, click investigate element
change the element nearby
<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default" translate="no">to 
<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default" translate="no" style="height:600px; width:700px; overflow:scroll">
Or you can also do that on the child div.
